# Array issues (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

I created a small function that stores the book isbn, it's name and it's author. Everything is fine until I start to print out array. On every entery that completes the object into array, I want it to be printed one after another in new row, but this one is printing the objects from beginning every time when a new object is inserted. How do I fix this?

```
var books = [];
function blaBla(){
    while(isbn != null || name != null || writer != null){
        var isbn = window.prompt("Enter ISBN");
        var name = window.prompt("Enter name of the book");
        var writer = window.prompt("Enter name of the writer");
        var patternString = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        var patternNum = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(isbn.match(patternNum)){
            if(name.match(patternString)){
                if(writer.match(patternString)){
                    books.push({
                        isbn: isbn,
                        name: name,
                        writer: writer
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i=0; i<books.length; i++){
            document.write(books[i].isbn + " - " + books[i].name + " - " + books[i].writer + "</br>");
        }
    }
}
```

PS: How do I make it even more "cleaner", so when I hit cancel on prompt, it automatically stops with entering data into array, while, if i stop it on the "writer" prompt, it deletes previous entries for that object (last isbn and last name of the book)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `for` loop that does the writing is inside the `while` loop that is still accumulating the array. Fix up your indentation for clarity, and use the `&&` operator instead of nested `if` statements.

Comment: ...or if this is the only reason for the `books` array, then you can get rid of it and put the `document.write` up where the `.push()` currently is.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a little more context as to what this function is doing so we can help make your code cleaner as requested. I've separated the collection logic from the display logic here, and also used a `while (true)` loop with breaks on null or invalid inputs which will stop the collection of data.

Please note that prompt/alert boxes are a hideous way of collecting user input though (very awkward user experience). Consider using a table, input fields, and some jQuery instead to add rows and validate what the user has entered into input boxes.

```js
var books = [];

function collectResponses() {
    var patternString = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var patternNum = /^[0-9]+$/;

    while (true) {
        var isbn = window.prompt("Enter ISBN");
        if (!isbn || !isbn.match(patternNum)) {
            break;
        }

        var name = window.prompt("Enter name of the book");
        if (!name || !name.match(patternNum)) {
            break;
        }

        var writer = window.prompt("Enter name of the writer");
        if (!writer || !writer.match(patternNum)) {
            break;
        }

        books.push({
            isbn: isbn,
            name: name,
            writer: writer
        });
    }
}

function displayResponses() {
    for (var i=0; i<books.length; i++){
        document.write(books[i].isbn + " - " + books[i].name + " - " + books[i].writer + "</br>");
    }
}
```